# script needed to Reset group permission to enclosed items in folder OS X Yosemite

Tags: file-permissions, osx-yosemite, applescript, osx-server

Error with Excel document falling read only on server shared document. 
i'm looking for a script to apply "group" folder permission to all included files.Every day at a specific time 8pm.to fix problem. 
I am doing it manually right now!(apply to enclosed items)
I have research google and not very good with scripting.
No valid solution.
I have found multiple answer dating back to 2008 to 2012.
Help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

OSX Yosemite 10.10 server
AFP and SMB sharing

Comment: path to files? group name?

Comment: Folder is in shared document, we have staff and admin groupe

Comment: That... doesn't help. I need the Full Filesystem path e.g. `/home/user/folder` and I need the group name, not just `admin` and `staff`

Comment: Sry i keep hitting return key and getting stuck...Folder is in shared document_ is there a way to apply the folder permission to the enclosed items periodically? I have basic knowledge of scripting and can apply path....I have multiple folder with different group permission! I could give them read write permission inside specific folder that would also fix the problem. Thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I use to repair one specific share on my server everyday at 2am.

Repair Script (Saved in /Users/Shared/Scripts)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Document Control
# ---------------
# Filename: repair_FileShare.sh
# Description: Repairs ownership and permissions on all files in the file share
# Version: 1.0

# Local Variables
# ---------------
SharePath=/path/to/shared/folder/

# Repair Routine
# ---------------

# Unlock all files
chflags -R nouchg $SharePath

# Remove all ACL permissions
chmod -RN $SharePath

# Set Ownership - OwnerName:GroupName (Example MrSmith:FinanceTeam)
chown -R root:admin $SharePath

# Set Posix Permissions - Check out http://permissions-calculator.org for more on what 770 means 
chmod -R 770 $SharePath

# Add ACL for Active Directory Group
chmod -R +a "DOMAINNAME\\AD_Group_Name allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" $SharePath
```

Launch daemon used to run the script everyday at 2am

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.yourdomain.repair_FileShare</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Scripts/repair_FileShare.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>02</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save it as /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.repair_FileShare.plist
Then use these commands to load it:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.repair_FileShare.plist;
sudo chmod 600 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.repair_FileShare.plist;
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.repair_FileShare.plist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root issue may well be with the `.TemporaryItems` folder. Office apps have historically created folders and temp files in this folder.

The permissions on this folder are quite specific and need to be set to `1770` (sticky bit set)

`sudo chmod 1770 $pathtoshare/.TemporaryItems`

You may also run into issues if users on different machines have the same UID of 501 (which they often will).

If the users on your client machines have the same UID, you may see clashes occur in this `.TemporaryItems` folder

This folder can be temporarily set aside or cleared if you are sure no clients have files open. You should then create a new .TemporaryItems folder a tthe root of the share

`sudo mkdir $pathtoshare/.TemporaryItems`

`sudo chmod 1770 $pathtoshare/.TemporaryItems`